# JSON in uri request

Tags: php, json, query-string

What if I pass my searching params in uri request in json-format like this:

```
http://example.com/?search={"title":"Some+Title","category":12}
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/?title=Some+Title&category=12
```

Before decode json-request I can filter it with some functions like strip_tags(), strpslashes(), etc... But I can do the same with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] with serialize()/unserialize(). Or apply string-filters to N string-params of request, not once to whole request.

Which way do you think will be better, usable and faster to process?

#### With json

```
$request = $_GET['search'];
$request = stripslaches(strip_tags($request));
$params  = json_decode($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

The characters *{* and *}* are unsafe according to RFC 1738 2.2. They must therefore be encoded before being transferred over a network.

The character *:* is reserved according to RFC 1738 2.2. It must therefore be encoded before being transferred over a network unless it is used for the purpose for which it was reserved.

Don't use `$request = striplashes(strip_tags($request))`. If `$_GET['search']` does not `json_decode` sucessfully, treat it as faulty input; don't try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an encoded JSON string is possible, as any string (you should [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/function.urldecode.php) it though, no stripping needed) but it's *not* really a good way to do it - use the standard way of passing data in request - if you have only simple data to send, just translate it into traditional GET variables (it's really easy, e.g. with [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php) as Tomasz suggests). You may also run into difficulities with the request URI length (see [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/523100)) if you pack too much data into the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead of passing JSON throw URL? HTTP_build_query is specially designed to pass data throw url params.

Applying this filter to whole `param_str` of URL may cause unexpected behaviour, besides fact that is actually little bit faster.
I think that you should pass every one parameter throw your filter functions.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just represent everything with JSON?

```
http://www.example.com/{"article":"something","page":12,"fragment":"#menu"}
```

Query strings are already used to represent flat lists of key-value pairs, so what problem does your JSON solution solve? You'll just be adding a new layer of complexity without any benefits.